# Tab delimited text file to Excel file with text formatted

Tags: excel, vbscript, format, vba

I am new to VB Programming .I want to convert a text file into a excel file.The text file is comma seperated and Unicode file.And the converted excel file should have all fields in text format(To preserve the prefixed Zeros).After converting the text file to excel with the below code,the zeros are truncated in the excel file.First i am converting the text file with comma delimited to tab delimited and loading the tab delimited text file into excel.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("SOURCE_FILE_PATH.txt", ForReading,False,-1)
strContents = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strContents = Replace(strContents, ",", vbTab)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("SOURCE_FILE_PATH.txt", ForWriting, True, -1)
objFile.Write strContents
objFile.Close
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
objWorkbook.Saveas WScript.Arguments.Item(1),51
objWorkbook.Close False
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("Target_XLSX_FILE_PATH.xlsx") 
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objRange = objExcel.Range("A:K")
objRange.NumberFormat = "@"--converting to text format
objExcel.Save 
objWorkbook.Close False
objexcel.Quit
```

In the line
 Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
 The tab delimited file is loaded in to various columns with Genetal format.After i convert that to text format also,The zeros won't be there.
 Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: ... So, what's the question?

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the above script,the tab delimited text file is opened in excel file as general format.But i want the tab delimited file should be opened as text formatted in excel sheet.So that i can have the prefixed zeroes.In the script,At last i am converting the columns to text format.But the zeros are already lost after                                                         Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
line

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to actually use `FSO` for this, if you're not going to do anything to the data inside the text file prior to importing to Excel.

This is my data:

[image]

This is the code:

```
Sub TextOpen()
    arrtext = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2))
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Users\jeromem\Desktop\BK201.txt", Comma:=True, FieldInfo:=arrtext
End Sub
```

This is the result after running:

[image]

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb223513%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for the `OpenText` method and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb241018(v=office.12).aspx) for the `FieldInfo` data types. As you can see there, text format is equal to `2`.

`arrtext` is basically read as, `for column 1 of text, apply format 2; for column 2 of text, apply format 2....`. We then feed this array to `FieldInfo`. We also set `Comma:=True` since this is the delimiter in your text file.

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: I want to call the vb script via Batch script?Can you please tell how to call this script via batch?

Comment: @santish: If you have to absolutely do it via `vbscript`, continue your way BUT prepend each number value with a `'`. This way, when it's opened in Excel, it will display as text first, and then just remove the `'` later when you've converted to text.

Comment: I have some 10000 rows.I can't do that manually each time for every column.And that too it should do automatically without any manual intervention through batch script.